# How to make extra padding in x-Axis values in MP Chart Library?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using **MPChart** Library for Multi data set. I am using three grouped graph for representation. For Spacing between grouped graphs I have used the following code snippet

```
groupSpace=0.8f
chart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(startYear + chart.getBarData().getGroupWidth(groupSpace,barSpace) * groupCount);
chart.groupBars(startYear, groupSpace, barSpace);
```

By Using groupspace I am able to set margin between group bars. But I want to also set the same margin with x-Axis values,those are not set in proper margin.

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Have you made any changes in `XAxis`? Also add your `XAxis` configuration

Comment: Try `getXAxis().setSpaceMin(0.10f);` you can specify any float value here

Comment: @nayanabhoj I tried but did not worked

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
XAxis xl = chart.getXAxis();
xl.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
xl.setLabelCount(groupCount + 1, true);
xl.setValueFormatter((value, axis) -> String.valueOf((int) value));

...

chart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(startYear);
chart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(startYear + chart.getBarData().getGroupWidth(groupSpace,barSpace) * groupCount);
```

Comment: @Codelover, Check the answer and let me know